# Metric on product of metric spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X =X_1 \times X_2$ be the product of two metric spaces:
$$
{\mathrm{(}}{X}{\mathrm{,}}{d}_{1}{\mathrm{)}}\hspace{0.33em}\text{and}\hspace{0.33em}{\mathrm{(}}{X}{\mathrm{,}}{d}_{2}{\mathrm{)}}
$$

Show that the following are metrics on $X$.

1. $
   {d}{\mathrm{(}}{x}{\mathrm{,}}{y}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{{=}}\sqrt{{d}_{1}{\mathrm{(}}{x}_{1}{\mathrm{,}}{y}_{1}{\mathrm{)}}^{2}\mathrm{{+}}{d}_{2}{\mathrm{(}}{x}_{2}{\mathrm{,}}{y}_{2}{\mathrm{)}}^{2}}
   $
2. $
   \mathit{\rho}{\mathrm{(}}{x}{\mathrm{,}}{y}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{{=}}\max\left[{{d}_{1}\mathrm{(}{x}_{1}\mathrm{,}{y}_{1}\mathrm{),}{d}_{2}\mathrm{(}{x}_{2}\mathrm{,}{y}_{2}\mathrm{)}}\right]
   $

Comment: What work have you done so far?

Comment: I am just stuck on triangle inequality for the first one I think about cauchy_Schwartz inequality

Comment: Prove the triangle inequality in 1. in just the way you prove it in the case  $X_1=X_2=\mathbb R$ with $d_1(x,y)=d_2(x,y)=|x-y|$. Just about word-for-word.

Comment: @user416990: You should check out https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference
This should help you improve the formatting of your post. Way too much use of \mathrm (you dont neet it for commata, plus signs etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps to think of working in the real vectorspace $\mathbb{R}^2$ and think about different norms, in your case the 2-norm and the $\infty$-norm.

As you pointed out in the comments, you are having trouble with the triangle inequality. First, observe that
$$
d(x,y) = \bigg\| \left( \begin{array}{c} d_1(x_1,y_1) \\ d_2(x_2,y_2)\end{array}\right)\bigg\|_2 = 
\sqrt{ d_1(x_1,y_1)^2 + d_1(x_1,y_1)^2}.
$$
Let $z = (z_1,z_2) \in X$. Then, you can use monotonicity of the square root and $(\cdot)^2$, namely that for positive $a,b$ you get
$$
a \leq b \implies \sqrt{a} \leq \sqrt{b} \text{ and } a^2 \leq b^2.
$$

Concretely, you calculate
$$
d_1(x_1,y_1) \leq d_1(x_1, z_1) + d_1(z_1,y_1) \implies d_1(x_1,y_1)^2 \leq d_1(x_1, z_1)^2 + d_1(z_1,y_1)^2
$$
and similarly for $d_2$. Then you can use monotonicity of the square root to derive an expression like this
$$
d(x,y) \leq \dots \leq  \bigg\| \left( \begin{array}{c} d_1(x_1,z_1) + d_1(z_1, y_1) \\ d_2(x_2,z_2) + d_2(z_2,y_2\end{array}\right)\bigg\|_2 = 
\bigg\| \left( \begin{array}{c} d_1(x_1,z_1) \\ d_2(x_2,z_2)\end{array}\right) + \left(\begin{array}{c} d_1(z_1,y_1) \\ d_2(z_2,y_2)\end{array}\right)\bigg\|_2 
\leq \dots
$$
Hopefully, you can take it from here and finish the proof. A similar line of argument applies to your second problem.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot can you give me a similar hint for the second one thanks in advance.

Comment: @user416990: It is very similar to the first problem, difference being that instead of the 2-norm you now have to deal with the max-norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$. You should try it on your own first. If you encounter a problem, you can edit your original post showing your progress and specifying your question.

Comment: @user416990 Just leave a comment, if you need help in a concrete step of completing the proof.

Comment: İ am just trying thanks a lot

Comment: @user416990: Have you been able to solve the problem? If you found my answer helpful you should consider accepting it. [Why should we accept answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/)

Comment: Ok i did thanks a lot

Comment: @user416990: You're welcome. I'm glad you found my answer useful!